# API response json to C# object

Tags: c#, json

So I got kind of a weird format returned from the api I'm calling it's the following:

```
[
    [
        1609065000000,
        "22739.71000000",
        "22795.73000000",
        "22700.39000000",
        "22779.08000000",
        "38.81782800",
        1609065899999,
        "883167.94526884",
        2261,
        "18.58965200",
        "423036.58181400",
        "0"
    ]
]
```

```
    public static class StringExtensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<Candlestick> ToCandleStickList(this string jsonObject)
        {
            var candleStickList = new List<Candlestick>();
            var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<object[]>>(jsonObject);
            foreach (var obj in list)
            {
                candleStickList.Add(new Candlestick
                {
                    OpenTime = (long)obj[0],
                    Open = double.Parse((string)obj[1]),
                    High = double.Parse((string)obj[2]),
                    Low = double.Parse((string)obj[3]),
                    Close = double.Parse((string)obj[4]),
                    Volume = double.Parse((string)obj[5]),
                    CloseTime = (long)obj[6],
                    QuoteAssetVolume = double.Parse((string)obj[7]),
                    NumberOfTrades = (long)obj[8],
                    TakerBuyBaseAssetVolume = double.Parse((string)obj[9]),
                    TakerBuyQuoteAssetVolume = double.Parse((string)obj[10])
                });
            }

            return candleStickList;
        }
    }
```

```
    public class Candlestick
    {
        public long OpenTime { get; set; }
        public double Open { get; set; }
        public double High { get; set; }
        public double Low { get; set; }
        public double Close { get; set; }
        public double Volume { get; set; }
        public long CloseTime { get; set; }
        public double QuoteAssetVolume { get; set; }
        public long NumberOfTrades { get; set; }
        public double TakerBuyBaseAssetVolume { get; set; }
        public double TakerBuyQuoteAssetVolume { get; set; }
    }
```

I use the static method as follows

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Candlestick>> GetCandleSticks(string symbol, string interval)
        {
            var endpoint = $"api/v3/klines?symbol={symbol}&interval={interval}";
            var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(endpoint);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var result = (await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()).ToCandleStickList();

                return result;
            }

            throw new Exception($"");
        }
```

Does anyone got any suggestions for better code? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does your code work as expected. We only review working code.

Comment: My code works as expected yeah.

Comment: @pacmaninbw I was looking for a better way to cast the string to an object. Or overall code smells that would get noticed. I think I clarified that in the last sentece of my question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Json.NET` has a very useful `JsonConverter` which you can use to add a custom JsonConverter. Which what you actually need.

So, you can do something like this :

```
public class CandlestickConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Candlestick);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader , Type objectType , object existingValue , JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if(reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var candle = ( existingValue as Candlestick ?? new Candlestick() );

        var array = JArray.Load(reader);

        candle.OpenTime = array.ElementAtOrDefault(0)?.ToObject<long>(serializer) ?? 0;
        candle.Open = array.ElementAtOrDefault(1)?.ToObject<double>(serializer) ?? 0;
        candle.High = array.ElementAtOrDefault(2)?.ToObject<double>(serializer) ?? 0;
        candle.Low = array.ElementAtOrDefault(3)?.ToObject<double>(serializer) ?? 0;
        candle.Close = array.ElementAtOrDefault(4)?.ToObject<double>(serializer) ?? 0;
        candle.Volume = array.ElementAtOrDefault(5)?.ToObject<double>(serializer) ?? 0;
        candle.CloseTime = array.ElementAtOrDefault(6)?.ToObject<long>(serializer) ?? 0;
        candle.QuoteAssetVolume = array.ElementAtOrDefault(7)?.ToObject<double>(serializer) ?? 0;
        candle.NumberOfTrades = array.ElementAtOrDefault(8)?.ToObject<long>(serializer) ?? 0;
        candle.TakerBuyBaseAssetVolume = array.ElementAtOrDefault(9)?.ToObject<double>(serializer) ?? 0;
        candle.TakerBuyQuoteAssetVolume = array.ElementAtOrDefault(10)?.ToObject<double>(serializer) ?? 0;

        return candle;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer , object value , JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var candle = (Candlestick) value;
        serializer.Serialize(writer ,
            new[]
            {
                candle.OpenTime,
                candle.Open,
                candle.High,
                candle.Low,
                candle.Close,
                candle.Volume,
                candle.CloseTime,
                candle.QuoteAssetVolume,
                candle.NumberOfTrades,
                candle.TakerBuyBaseAssetVolume,
                candle.TakerBuyQuoteAssetVolume
            });
    }
}
```

Now, using this custom converter you can use the `JsonConverter` attribute on the class like this :

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(CandlestickConverter))]
public class Candlestick
{
    ...
}
```

Now you can do this directly :

```
var candles = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Candlestick>>(jsonObject);
```

So, you don't need to use extensions, you only need to do a custom converter which is the proper way to handle Json serialization when using `Json.NET`.

Comment: Thanks I'll give this a try and keep the post updated.

Comment: I gave it a try and ran in following error ```Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type Candlestick  because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"
value"}) to deserialize correctly.```. I'll post my question about stackoverflow about this question. But to clarify the refactoring didn't exactly work as expected.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65477922/deserializing-json-response-to-c-sharp-object-error

Comment: Resolved and the code is a lot cleaner now thanks for the code review.

Answer (score 1):

A few quick observations:

String extensions is generally a bad idea because `string` is such a common type.

Conversion code can be written more defensively. Use `TryParse` instead of `Parse` and if `TryParse` fails then handle that by throwing an  Exception, or some other error handling.

Throwing a generic exception with no message is not great.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick observations, I'll try and use TryParse instead of Parse. Do you have a recommendation what to use instead of using a string extensions?

Comment: @MounirMehjoub a local method inside ```GetCandleSticks``` could be an idea.